# Will Android receivers unregister automatically on application exit?

Tags: android, android-activity, receiver

When my Android application needs to register a receiver, I've been registering in `Activity.onCreate()` and unregistering in `Activity.onDestroy()` (I think I'm supposed to be using `onPause()` and `onResume()` instead, but that's not really the point):

```
public class Foo extends Activity {
    private Receiver bar = null;

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        this.registerReceiver(this.bar = new Receiver(), new IntentFilter());
    }

    @Override public void onDestroy(Bundle bundle) {
        this.unregisterReceiver(this.bar);
    }
}
```

Is unregistering the receiver actually necessary, or will the framework handle it when my application exits?

Comment: BTW, calling onDestroy is not guaranteed since Android could just kill your process.

Comment: @Yaroslav I said "I think I'm supposed to be using onPause() and onResume() instead, but that's not really the point"

Answer (score 1):

You can handle receiver in onCreate and unregister receiver automatically on exit if using Android Lifecycle-aware component, for example

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getLifecycle().addObserver(new ReceiverLifecycleObserver(this, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED), new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: intent=" + intent);
        }
    }));
}

static class ReceiverLifecycleObserver implements LifecycleObserver {
    private final Context context;
    private final IntentFilter filter;
    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver;

    public ReceiverLifecycleObserver(Context context, IntentFilter filter, BroadcastReceiver receiver) {
        this.context = context;
        this.filter = filter;
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    public void onStart(LifecycleOwner owner) {
        context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    public void onStop(LifecycleOwner owner) {
        context.unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If registering a receiver in your Activity.onResume() implementation, you should unregister it in Activity.onPause(). (You won't receive intents when paused, and this will cut down on unnecessary system overhead)

Comment: Ignoring that, is it actually necessary to unregister a receiver when your application is about to exit?

Comment: Will you want to wake up your application if it's not running?. If so, you can register it in your Manifest file and that's all. Otherwise, unregister the receiver before user exits the app